# Project Texture onto SCNSphere

Tags: graphics, scenekit, texture-mapping

I have a SCNSphere which I map the following texture onto. I want to generate a "football" by mapping a hexagonal "black & white" texture on it. However the result is unsatisfying due to the projection of my rectangular texture onto the sphere.

[image: texture for sphere]

I have read that there is GDAL which potentially can pre-transform my image such that when projected onto the sphere it looks OK.

Does anybody have some hints how to his exactly ? The threads on this topics on SO are quite special and not explained well.

Comment: I used the image from here as a reference when I needed a football texture: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/sportsballs/

Comment: Great, that solved my problem. Thanks